# Terminal run configurations in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I wonder if it's possible to have some sort of a run configuration in VSCode that will open 2 terminal tabs (preferably by splitting 1 window into 2 terminal tabs vertically) and run 2 separate commands in them.

Use case: I have a repository with backend and frontend. When I have to develop this application, I need to execute:

```sh
cd ./backend
poetry run dev

# in 2nd tab
cd ./frontend
npm run dev
```

Every time I split terminal manually and manually run these commands. Is it possible to automate it? So I can click 1 button or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I've figured it out. My `tasks.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Run application",
      "dependsOn": ["Frontend", "Backend"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
    },
    {
      "label": "Frontend",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "cd frontend && npm run dev",
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "group": "development"
      },
    },
    {
      "label": "Backend",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "cd backend && poetry run dev",
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "group": "development"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I can run `Run application` task and it will do what I described.

The trick was to use `presentation.group` field